# Android : taking pictures and text from a website and putting them in a ListView

Tags: android, parsing, listview, xhtml, web

I have a very precise question:

I want to make an android application that can access this website http://www.cineklik.com/Showing-Now-Movies.aspx and then take the pictures of every movie in the Showing Now section and the title of this movie and put them both in a ListView (image on left and text on right or middle like in this example : http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

My main problem is that I don't know how to read data from this page because its source is very complex, so I need help for this particular issue most, but I would appreciate help on anything I can get !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to get a website's data you'll have to use an HTTPGet (if there is no API from that site). After that you'd be able to parse the response and use the data

Comment: You could use tools like Firebug to check the HTML and only save the data you need. They safe every movie in an own table.